# MatrixTransform how do you tell if its increasing or decreasing

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using MatrixTransform on a canvas that is pinched as follows:

```
var transformation = MyCanvas.RenderTransform as MatrixTransform;
var matrix = transformation == null ? Matrix.Identity:transformation.Matrix;

matrix.ScaleAt(e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X,
               e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.Y,
               e.ManipulationOrigin.X,
               e.ManipulationOrigin.Y);

Matrix m = MyCanvas.RenderTransform.Value;
```

How do I tell if it's increasing or decreasing? Is there a property I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got you right, but if you need to know if the resulting matrix has a scaling factor less than one or greater than one, you could simply check the [Matrix.M11](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.matrix.m11.aspx) and [Matrix.M22](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.matrix.m22.aspx) properties. Unless you also rotate, they give you the scaling factors in x and y direction. The resulting total scaling depends on how you define it. The simplest definition would perhaps be the arithmetic mean value (M11 + M22) / 2:

```
matrix.ScaleAt(e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X,
               e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.Y,
               e.ManipulationOrigin.X,
               e.ManipulationOrigin.Y);

var effectiveScale = (matrix.M11 / matrix.M22) / 2;
```

EDIT: After reading the comment I have to add that as long as you scale independently in x and y direction, you might well zoom in in one and at the same time zoom out in the other direction. To avoid this situation and get a well defined uniform zoom factor you would first have to calculate a mean zoom factor by something like

```
var scale = (e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X +
             e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.Y) / 2;
```

This value is greater than one for a zoom in, and less than one for a zoom out manipulation. You would then scale the Matrix like this:

```
matrix.ScaleAt(scale, scale,
               e.ManipulationOrigin.X, e.ManipulationOrigin.Y);
```

Comment: Thanks Clemens, I've read this from you elsewhere on Stackover. I'm trying to be able to tell whether the pinch is a zoom in or a zoom out.

Comment: Clemens, my effective scale factor here is always 0.5?